# Can inverse fourier transform be formulated in terms of residue?

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, residue-calculus

Today I ran into a peculiar problem when trying to perform the inverse fourier transform of $\frac{1}{a+jw}$ where a is some number

$$
\mathcal{F^{-1}}(\frac{1}{a+jw}) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a+jw} \, e^{jwt} \, \mathrm{d} w
$$

Then let's multiple top and bottom by $2\pi i$

$$
\mathcal{F^{-1}}(\frac{1}{a+jw}) = \frac{2\pi i}{2\pi} \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a+jw} \, e^{jwt} \, \mathrm{d} w 
$$

On the right hand side we have the residue on the contour $[-\infty, \infty]$

Then 
$$
\mathcal{F^{-1}}(\frac{1}{a+jw}) = i Res(e^{jwt};aj)
$$

Finally, we have $$\mathcal{F^{-1}}(\frac{1}{a+jw}) = i e^{-at}$$

But wait a minute, where did our "i" come from?

Can someone verify whether I have properly formulated the inverse transform as a residue? If so, can someone spot the mistake?

Comment: You're combining 'i' and 'j', and that's not good. It would be best to edit. You can compute the transform using residues. However, you have missed a point: If $t > 0$ then $e^{j\omega t}$ is bounded in the upper half plane, but not in the lower. If $t < 0$, then $e^{j\omega t}$ is bounded in the lower half plane, but not in the upper. For $t > 0$ you close the contour in the upper half plane and for $t < 0$ you close in the lower half plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take the $j$ out of $a+jw$, i.e.

$\frac{1}{a+jw} = \frac{-j}{-ja+w}$.

Then you can also take $-j$ out of the integral and this factor cancels with $j$. The j is the imaginary unit. Recall: $\oint \frac{f(w)}{w-a} dw = 2 \pi i f(a)$.

Of course you have a residue!